# How to set up MVC for JQuery under the script folder of .Net MVC applicaiton?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing MVC application using MVC4 with razor view engine. In order to maintain data flow I am using JQuery for that I have placed all JQuery plugin files under the Script folder. But every time I am writing my JQuery code at below section of page. I am using same procedure to all my pages (View). But writing JQuery code in each and every page at below section It feels me not good.

Please guide me someone what are the best approaches to write JQuery Or how can I use MVC folder structure under the script folder?

Can anybody tell how to setup MVC for JQuery under the Script folder of .Net MVC application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard practice is view should not have any inline scripts. Instead all scripts should go in a seperate JS file. You can add reference to JS file in your _Layout.cshtml. 
Also, generally application uses lots of JS script libraries, so it's better to seperate the application JS files and 3rd party script files for that you can create following folder structure -

```
-Scripts
--App >>> all application specific script files will go here.
--Library >>> All 3rd party scripts will go here, like - jquery, jquery ui, modernizer, etc.
```

Comment: can give information about MVC structure implementation for JQuery. like where to write **jquery-Model**, where to write **jquery-view**, where to write **jquery-controller**.

Comment: Instead of using the jQuery for client side MVC framework, think of AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `asp.net mvc 3` you can add the jQuery files on the `_Layout.cshtml` page, for sample:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
```

if you are using `asp.net mvc 4` just add without `Url.Content` helper, and razor will resolve it for you:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Until now, nothing new, but, if you have the same jQuery code for all Views of your project, you could add this javascript code on the `_Layout.cshtml` file. Anyway, you also could add another custom `.js` file in the `Scripts` folder and add it on as you do with the `jquery.js` file.

You are not obligate to use `Scripts` folder, it is just a template suggested by Microsoft. I think there is no best approach to add javascript files, it is about how your team is confortable to work, since it is organized.

With a custom, creating a spefici folder for custom files, you could add:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/MyScripts.js"></script>
```

If you have a custom script for just a page, I would add this there instead creating a custom file just for this page. Works too, but maintenance will grow up.